# Enable another div once a radio and a valid number selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a radio button set named "custom_50" and a price field. I would like to enable "first_name" only if one of the option of radio is selected and there's valid value for "Priceset".

They all seems to work on its own in different jQuery, but when combine them in the if statement, it doesnt work. Can anyone help please?

```
   CRM.$(function($) {
       showNameEmail();
       $('#priceset [price], input[name=\"custom_50\"]').bind('change keyup click blur', showNameEmail);

       function showNameEmail() {
           if ((($('input[name=\"custom_50\"]:checked').length > 0)) && (calculateTotalFee() > 0)) {
               $('#editrow-first_name').fadeIn('slow');
           }
           else {
               $('#editrow-first_name').slideUp('slow');
           }
       }
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or at least show all relevant code - your HTML code and  `calculateTotalFee()`

Comment: Note that `bind` was discouraged in favor of `on` in jQuery 1.7.